# Obscure primitive data types against cheating

Tags: unity, c#, security, anti-cheat, hacks

im trying to create lightweight value obscurer, against possibility to blatantly change primitive values in memory editor. Such as cheat engine. Here's what i have to far.

```
/// <summary>
/// Obscure for type int.
/// </summary>
public class ObscuredInt{

    public ObscuredInt() {
        this.value = 0;
    }

    public ObscuredInt(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private int _a;
    private int _b;

    /// <summary>
    /// Current obscure value.
    /// </summary>
    public int value {
        get {
            return _a + _b;
        }
        set {
            _a = Random.Range(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
            _b = value - _a;
        }
    }
}
```

usage

```
ObscuredInt health = new ObscuredInt(5);
health.value = 10;

printInConsle(health.value);
```

This works by simply never storing actual value, but rather a combination of two integers, which sum represents the value. That way the value is actually never cached long time in the memory. So finding it in a primitive way using cheat engine is not possible.

**My question**

I've seen other examples of obscuring, which involve conversion to binary or string hashing or other quite heavy operations.

This example is of course much more lightweight, how is this example worse than more advanced hashing or conversions. What flaws do you see with this example? What can you suggest?

Thank you

Comment: Security through obscurity is not security at all.

Comment: Additionally, you kill your performance by wrapping all your primitives in dubious classes; while for a hacker what you think is obscurity is really just a fun puzzle to crack stepping through assembly and data.

Comment: @Almo I understand that complete validation can only be achieved with server side solutions. But such simple solutions can be used for example simple mobile games.

Comment: @MattJensJensen Yes, of course, this type of solutions would be the best for singleton data type of usages, such as health or armor, which exist for the all game-play time. Creating hundreds of temporary instances every frame is not good for anything really.

Comment: @YoungDeveloper I don't think I'd consider a singleton for this (a singleton is basically just a static global wrapped in a class that you allocate at will), I just mean, if you want to use an `int`, just use an `int`, you gain very little theoretical obscurity with `ObscuredInt` and lose so much simplicity and efficiency wrapping it in a class that indirectly calculates the value in the name of "security".

Comment: @MattJensJensen It's a very little overhead for cached instance, which is not created a lot of times. Memory is not the problem in this case, allocation and garbage collection is. If it sleeps in the memory and again, .value is not accessed hundreds of time per frame, i see no problems. 
Also, i would not consider cutting off cheaters (kids and teenagers) who only know how to use memory editor is a little gain. That's like 98% of potential cheaters, there's extremely small proportion who will go in deep.

Comment: @YoungDeveloper You won't be preventing any real cheating with this method, you'll only be preventing users from doing what they want with software on their computer. And a good portion of people who cheat locally just use a tool pre-built for that game by a real hacker who built a tool to exploit that game if basic CheatEngine attacks don't work. I'd just recommend you to focus on the more important things in your game first, it's more important that your game is fun and runs smoothly than it is that they can't cheat themselves out of playing it how you designed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strategies to Defeat Memory Editors for Cheating - Desktop Games](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9832/strategies-to-defeat-memory-editors-for-cheating-desktop-games)

Comment: Why would you do that anyway? In a multiplayer game, any data worth manipulating should be server-sided. In a singleplayer game, the player is only cheating themselves. Why prevent them from playing your game the way they want? When they think it's more fun to play with infinite health, why not let them?

Comment: @MattJensJensen If i create successful game enough for people to write specific hacks i will not be sad. You are going into theory of creating games, which i am very familiar of. This is programming question and problem, i don't see why mentioning on what i should be more focusing on matters.

Comment: @YoungDeveloper I'm just trying to help you avoid programming in something that is going to kill performance and cause difficult to find issues with cache and optimization.

Comment: @MattJensJensen Thank you for your time, have a good day!

Comment: please see this link http://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/09/02/a-practical-tutorial-to-hack-and-protect-unity-games/

Comment: As a gamer I would find something like this extremely annoying. Seriously, why bother and annoy users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major flaw is that you are adding random values between `int.MinValue` and  `int.MaxValue` leaving no more space for your real value. Okay, the default in C# is to not perform range checks, [but this can be changed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx).

In order to keep the whole `int` value range open for your real values  I would suggest to use an [XOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx) operation instead.

```
public int value {
    get {
        return _a ^ _b;
    }
    set {
        _a = Random.Range(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
        _b = value ^ _a;
    }
}
```

Applying the same "mask" a second time with [XOR restores the original value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher). The result of XOR is always in the `int`-range and never overflows. XOR is very fast and does not involve range checks.

---

Alternatively you could wrap your code in `unchecked` statements.

```
public int value {
    get {
        unchecked {
            return _a + _b;
        }
    }
    set {
        _a = Random.Range(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
        unchecked {
            _b = value - _a;
        }
    }
}
```

See: [Checked and Unchecked (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx).

---

Speed: The most expensive operation is the creation of the random number. If speed matters, consider making the random number static and create only one per session.

---

Safety: I think most cheat engines won't be smart enough to get around your trick. But of course, for human hackers that's another story.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i am not exactly sure what unchecked does in this matter but i will look into that.

Comment: I added a link to the [Checked and Unchecked (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, i will wait for possible other answers, if no more will pop up (and better :) ) i will accept yours as an answer. Thanks again, have a good day!